# Why my geojson doesn't work as I want to?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I want to use some layers of macrostat.org API. For example if I want to present this API call: https://macrostrat.org/api/paleogeography?interval_name=Permian&format=geojson then it appears like this: 
[My map look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWSOp.jpg) but I want to show it, like this:
[like on macrostat.org's site when I search for "Permian"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MCrG.png).

I tried like this:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([0, 0], 3);

    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=MY_TOKEN', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox.satellite',
        accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var geojsonFeature = { 

THE API CALL'S ANSWER FROM: https://macrostrat.org/api/paleogeography?interval_name=Permian&format=geojson 
};

L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature).addTo(mymap);
```

Of course I put the necessary `css` and `js` links of the `lealflet` in the header.

Comment: Does the GeoJSON have the lat / lng values reversed, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data actually not represent what you are finding for. This is about how Earth (the original continents) looks like in the Permian era, and not the Permian layer of the Earth.